# How to increase priority of template proposals in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, autocomplete

I am using Eclipse Indigo,I have created a template proposal by the name **Connection** (Similar to java.sql.Connection). This proposal, through additional comments, would prompt developer of any possible vulnerabilities that may occur using java.sql.Connection.

Is there any way to increase the priority of template proposal so that when I type ctrl+space my proposal,**Connection**, would be on top of eclipse's **Connection** proposal?

Answer (score 2):

If you type `Ctrl+Space+Space`, Eclipse should display **only** your Template Proposals.

This "Content Assist Cycling" behaviour is configured in `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced`.

Alternatively, rename your template to `connection` with a lowercase `c`, and it should appear at the top of the list.

Comment: Thanks for your response, dogbane. ctrl+space+space works perfectly but it displays only template proposals.

Renaming the proposal with lowercase c would not help if developer types the word with uppercase C.
Is there any way we can customize eclipse classes for this purpose.